# Using itertools groupby to sort lists and merge dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, group-by, python-itertools

I am looking to use python intertools groupby to make a function that groups small lists in to a bigger list. What I start with is a list of different datapoints with the following structure (called sortedData)

```
[
  [location, date, {item:quantity}],
  [location2, date, {item2:quantity2}],
  ...
]
```

I am trying to group them so that each location/date combination has a dictionary with all items and quantities, and that these lists are grouped by the location. Here is an example:

```
[
  [
    [Maine, 01062016, {apple:5, orange:2}],
    [Maine, 02042016,{apple:3, peach:2}]
  ],
  [
    [Vermont, 01032016, {peach:3}]
  ]
]
```

What I have so far is this code, but I am having trouble understanding how to use the group that is created, since it is not an iterable item. Now it gives a blank list, though it seems it should be appending things

```
def compileData(sortedData):    
    from itertools import groupby
    for key, locationGroup in groupby(sortedData, lambda x: x[0]):
        locationList=[]
        bigList=[]
        for date in locationGroup:
            locationList.append(date)
        locationList.append(locationGroup)
        for key, bigList in groupby(locationGroup, lambda x: x[1]):
            datePlace=[key[0],key[1],{}]
            for date in locationGroup:
                datePlace[2]=dict(list(date[2].items())+list(datePlace[2].items()))
                bigList.append(datePlace)
        return bigList
```

Let me know what you think, and if you have any better ideas to how to tackle this problem, let me know. I wrote it recursivley but the file I am using it on is too long, so it is too slow.

Comment: Could you add an example of what kind of output you're hoping for please?

Comment: "Using itertools groupby to sort" - `itertools.groupby` does no sorting. If you need to sort things, `itertools.groupby` will not help you do that. It can be helpful for processing sorted data, but something else needs to ensure the data is sorted.

Comment: Hi Mitch, The second block quote has the output I am looking for. (ie a list of lists of lists)

Comment: I think group is actually a more accurate word for what I am doing. I changed it in the post. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: can you provide a sample of your input?  (What does sortedData look like?)

Comment: Kelvin, I edited the post to make that more clear. It takes a list of lists.

Comment: I am a bit confused, your second quote block looks like a sample of your first quote block.  What do you want to happen, to sum by date / product?  BTW if you're going to have a long for your date you're better off with YYYYMMDD it makes sorting on date doable.

Comment: The second quote block has unbalanced brackets. There is an extra `]` at the end (or a missing `[` at the beginning.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def update_with_ignore(a, b):
    '''Copy only new entries from B to A'''
    for k,v in b.items():
        a.setdefault(k,v)

def compileData(sortedData):
    result = []
    sortedData = sorted(sortedData, key=itemgetter(0,1))
    for location, group in groupby(sortedData, key=itemgetter(0)):
        l = []
        for date, group in groupby(group, key=itemgetter(1)):
            d = {}
            for datum in group:
                update_with_ignore(d, datum[2])
            l.append([location, date, dict(d)])
        result.append(l)
    return result


in_data = [
    ["Maine", "01062016", {"apple":5}],
    ["Maine", "02042016", {"apple":3}],
    ["Maine", "01062016", {"orange":2}],
    ["Vermont", "01032016", {"peach":3}],
    ["Maine", "02042016", {"peach":2}],
]
out_data = compileData(in_data)
assert out_data == [
 [['Maine', '01062016', {'apple': 5, 'orange': 2}],
  ['Maine', '02042016', {'apple': 3, 'peach': 2}]],
 [['Vermont', '01032016', {'peach': 3}]]]

in_data = [
    ["Maine", "01062016", {"apple":5}],
    ["Maine", "01062016", {"apple":4}],
    ["Maine", "02042016", {"apple":3}],
]
out_data = compileData(in_data)
assert out_data == [
 [['Maine', '01062016', {'apple': 5}],
  ['Maine', '02042016', {'apple': 3}]]]
```

Comment: Really nice.  @Amelia, wouldn't a dict be a better data structure for this all the way through?

Comment: Kelvin, do you mean having a dictionary like this {(location:date):{item:value}}

Comment: And Rob, thank you so much. I do like list comprehension, and honestly am not familiar with collections, operator, pprint, or assert, so I am going to stick with your second solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Robᵩ I am using this with my datafile and I am getting an error: that says can not concatenate str and int variables about the following code that was imported:
` 630         result = Counter()`
    631         for elem, count in self.items():
--> 632             newcount = count + other[elem]
    633             if newcount > 0:
    634                 result[elem] = newcount

what is this referring to? Can you tell what is getting concatenated here?

Comment: @AmeliaMcClure - I'm going to guess that one of your dictionary values is a string. My code will only work if all the dictionary values are integers.

Comment: @Robᵩ yup, you are right. I will clean up the data a little bit and try it again.

Comment: @Robᵩ, sorry to keep bugging you but the way the code is now, if there are multiple values for a location, date, key permutation, the values get added together. Instead, I would just like to ignore the second one. How could I change the code to pass if there is a duplication?